# pure python socket module

Tags: python, sockets, emulation

The socket module in python wraps the `_socket` module which is the C implementation stuff.  As well, socket.socket will take a `_sock` parameter that must implement the `_socket` interface.  In some regards `_sock` must be an actual instance of the underlying socket type from `_socket` since the C code does type checking (unlike pure python).

Given that you can pass in a socket-like object for `_sock`, it seems like you could write a socket emulator that you could pass in to socket.socket.  It would need to emulate the underlying socket behavior but in memory and not over a real network or anything.  It should not otherwise be distinguishable from `_socket`.

**What would it take to build out this sort of emulation?**

I know, I know, this is not terribly practical.  In fact, I learned the hard way that using regular sockets was easier and fake sockets were unnecessary.  I had thought that I would have better control of a test environment with fake sockets.  Regardless of the time I "wasted", I found that I learned a bunch about sockets and about python in the process.

I was guessing any solution would have to be a stack of interacting objects like this:

```
something_that_uses_sockets (like XMLRPCTransport for ServerProxy)
    |
    V
socket.socket
    |
    V
FakeSocket
    |
    V
FakeNetwork
    |
    V
FakeSocket ("remote")
    |
    V
socket.socket
    |
    V
something_else_that_uses_sockets (like SimpleXMLRPCServer)
```

It seems like this is basically what is going on for real sockets, except for a real network instead of a fake one (plus OS-level sockets), and `_socket` instead of FakeSocket.

**Anyway, just for fun, any ideas on how to approach this?**

Incidently, with a FakeSocket you could do some socket-like stuff in Google Apps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already been done. [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) uses this extensively for unit tests of its protocol implementations. A good starting place would be looking at [some of Twisted's unit tests](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.1.0/twisted/test/test_protocols.py).

In essence, you'd just call [makeConnection](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.BaseProtocol.html#makeConnection) on your protocol with a transport that isn't connected to a real socket. Super easy!

Comment: Awesome!  That is just what I was looking for.  Maybe I should finally get around to looking into twisted. :)